# Default GetHashCode versus garbage collection

Tags: c#, .net, hash, garbage-collection, hashset

I want to have dictionary `Dictionary<MyType,Something>` or hash set `HashSet<MyType>`. In my application it holds that any two different instances of type MyType are never equal. Is it safe to use default implementation of GetHashCode and Equals in this case?

I am not sure how GetHashCode is implemented. But I always imagined that it is something like memory location of the object. Is this true?

If so then I would like to know what happens when garbage collector relocates the object? Can this happen? Could this cause that the object of MyType cannot be found in dictionary anymore?

Comment: I did not ask about what Equals does. I know this very well. I am unsure about unsure about GetHashCode and whether garbage collector can relocate the object and change the return value of GetHashCode. I have done minor edit to title and text of question to make this more obvious.

Comment: Sorry @B0B, Stackoverflow has become a mess of people not even trying to help but instead thinking that the goal is to just close questions.  To answer your question,  Object.GetHashCode "Serves as a hash function for a particular object, and is suitable for use in algorithms and data structures that use hash codes, such as a hash table."  

It will compare them as reference types.  What you are doing is proper as long as you are always looking them up by reference - as that's how they are also Equal.

Comment: Any garbage collection moving around will not affect an Object's hashcode.

Comment: @TheSoftwareJedi Thank you. Your comment helped me.